# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError even add dependencies in build.gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, wsdl, classnotfoundexception

Good day,

Base on https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/TopDownAxis2WebService/td_tutorial.html ,
I successful up the web service with my `wsdl` file. The different thing from the website is, I start my webservice in `Jboss EAP`, the tutorial was using `TomCat` as example.

I can curl request to http://localhost:8080/eai/services/MyDelegateBeanService successfully.

I would like to make some changes inside the `MyDelegateBeanServiceSkeleton.java` file, and I need some third party library, for example, `com.google.guava`. Thus, I try to add gradle on this project.

I create a build.gradle as follow:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "myeai"

repositories { 
    mavenCentral() 
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.guava:guava:17.0"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
}
```

I can run `gradle build`, `gradle eclipse` successfully without error, and I can see the `guava` library appear in the reference library:
[image]

In my java code, I can see my import is without compilation error as well:

```
import com.google.common.base.Strings;

System.out.println("item is " + Strings.isNullOrEmpty(reader.getText()));
```

However, when I curl again, I will hit the following error:

```
[ERROR] com/google/common/base/Strings
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Strings

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Strings from [Module "deployment.allpocEAR.ear.eai.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 47 more
```

May I know what is my mistaken?

I have try to restart my EAP server in jboss also the same:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that I should use compile instead of implementation:

```
compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.2"
compile "com.google.guava:guava:17.0"
```